# Webpage parallax background jitters when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax, jitter

I coded my [first website](https://www.jessepanther.com/) and I wanted a parallax effect on my background when scrolling. It works, but on some computers &/or on some browsers &/or on some window sizes, the background jitters up and down when scrolling, while still sort of maintaining the parallax effect. I cannot figure out exactly what combination leads to the issue, it seems inconsistent.

In css I have a vertically repeating background image on the body of my page (the hexagon pattern):

```
body {
   background: #fff9ed;
   background-image: url("hexagon-side.png"), url("hexagon-side.png");
   background-position: 0px 0px, 100% 0px;
   background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y;
}
```

Then I used the following javascript that creates the parallax effect, making the hexagons move slower than other elements when you scroll:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   let scrollTop =  window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
   var currentOffset = '0px ' + scrollTop / 1.2 + 'px, 100% ' + scrollTop / 1.2 + 'px';
   document.getElementById("parallax").style.backgroundPosition = currentOffset;
});
```

Finally my body in the html file has the id parallax:
 `<body id="parallax">`

Is there a way to fix this issue? Is there a better way to achieve this same effect? What might be causing this?

Comment: The JS setting the offset can be quite jittery.
Have you tried setting the `background-attachment` to `fixed` on the body (or #parallax)? That should smoothen it out.

Comment: After testing it on a few computers, this did it. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

to the css body, and changing the currentOffset to be

```
var currentOffset = '0px ' + scrollTop / -3 + 'px, 100% ' + scrollTop / -3 + 'px';
```

Fixed the jittering issues.